# WEPopover (UIPopover) Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover

I am trying to implement this WEPopover API into my app.  I have a UIBarButton Item in the NavBar that I want to have 5 choices of buttons/cells in the popup.

I can only seem to make it so that it has 1 button from the navbar, or if I assign the button to a tableivewcell, it can have more than one button.  But I can't seem to combine the two.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are setting the size correctly when you create the popover.

Look in the WePopover example code for references to contentSizeForViewInPopver